# Python + Flask-SQLAlche + PostgreSQL: Many to One relation error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relationship, many-to-one

I'm having trouble making the relationship of two tables. Are they:

**db.py:**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**floor.py:**

```
from db import db

class Floor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'floor'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500))

    positions = db.relationship('Position', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def json(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'description': self.description}
```

**position.py:**

```
from db import db

class Position(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'position'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500))

    floor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('floor.id'))
    floor = db.relationship('Floor')

    db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'floor_id', name='uk_position_floor')

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def json(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'description': self.description, 'floor': self.floor}
```

But when you start the program the following error is displayed:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|Floor|floor, expression 'Position' failed to locate a name ("name 'Position' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.floor.Floor'>class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Tks,

Comment: Have you imported from `position.py` at any point before mapper configuration time? If not, then do so. The class must've been constructed for it to be found – just like the exception says.

Comment: Thank you. really did not need to import the class.

Comment: Sure, you don't need to import the class into floor.py since `relationship` accepts string names and it does a lookup on the [class registry](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.class_registry), but you do have to evaluate the class definition somehow for the Position class to exist at all :P